# Using the open source released "roslyn" to read code file and generate new code files

Tags: c#, roslyn

Where do I start?

in my current solution I have models like this:

```
public class MyAwesomeModel
{
 ....
}
```

I want to take the roslyn code project to parse the source files and go over the syntax trees to generate new code files. Take those source files and add them to a c# project file to import in my solution again in visual studio.

Where do I start. Cloning roslyn and just write a console app that reference all of roslyn and start digging into roslyn to find out how, or is there any blogs,documentatino that shows something like this.

Comment: What do you mean generate new code files? Generate based on what?

Comment: the original code files that contains my models

Comment: "Roslyn" is a dynamic compiler.  So your question of generating "new code" doesn't make sense.  Now if your are asking about generating a "new binary" that would be a different question.

Comment: Well that is the end goal. But then we are into that black box of not knowing what happens with our code. Are you sure that it can not take a syntax tree and write the code? If thats not possible then yes, i just want to generate a new dll.

Comment: The Roslyn CodePlex site has an FAQs document. This may be a good starting point for understanding the Roslyn APIs - https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ. The code corresponding to the answers in this FAQ document are present in the form of unit tests in the Samples folder that is part of the Roslyn SDK Preview.

Also checkout the Samples and Walkthroughs page which also contains some guided 'getting started' walkthroughs that you may find helpful - https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Samples%20and%20Walkthroughs&referringTitle=Home.

Comment: I found that after i created this question. Just pasted my code into an answer also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was somewhat easy to do.

Create a console app and add reference to [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/3.8.0-3.final) in your project.

Here is the program that visited all properties in a source text:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

class ModelCollector : CSharpSyntaxWalker
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> Models { get; } = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    public override void VisitPropertyDeclaration(PropertyDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        var classnode = node.Parent as ClassDeclarationSyntax;
        if (!Models.ContainsKey(classnode.Identifier.ValueText))
        {
            Models.Add(classnode.Identifier.ValueText, new List<string>());
        }

        Models[classnode.Identifier.ValueText].Add(node.Identifier.ValueText);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var code = @"
                using System;
                using System.Collections.Generic;
                using System.Linq;
                using System.Text;

                namespace HelloWorld
                {
                    public class MyAwesomeModel
                    {
                        public string MyProperty {get;set;}
                        public int MyProperty1 {get;set;}
                    }

                }";

        var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);

        var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();
        var modelCollector = new ModelCollector();
        modelCollector.Visit(root);

        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(modelCollector.Models));
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to run this, you will need to install the following packages using NuGet: "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces" and "Json.NET".

Comment: Updated the example to use System.Text.Json and modernized a bit.