# Get project element code when saving project

Tags: c#, events, vsx

This question will be decomposed into a few sections for understandability purposes and because I haven't found any article/tutorial for it.

---

**Scenario**

Let:

- `myProject` be a C# Silverlight project in Visual Studio 14;
- `ModClass` be a class I modified in `myProject` (not saved yet);
- `ExistingClass` be a static class already existing in `myProject`.

In `ExistingClass` there's absolutely nothing, the class is simply there.
Also, `ModClass` has 2 fields name `fieldA` and `fieldB` respectively.

---

**Question**

**(1)** Is there a way to intercept the Save event to **(2)** get `ModClass`'s code and then **(3)** parse it so I get the fields for example [I can do that part] and finally **(4)** automatically write related stuff directly in `ExistingClass` (or completely regenerate `ExistingClass`'s code.

The question is broad but like I said, it's simply to show the context. What I really want to know is how point **1** can be achieved along with point **2**, since the rest is material for another question/research on my side.

---

**Example**

I do not have any verifyable example because I do not really know where to start if all this is even possible. I can still demonstrate the concept however with something like shown below.

*Before Save event:*

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class ExistingClass
    {
    }
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class ModClass
    {
        public int myInt; // This hasn't been saved yet
    }
}
```

*After Save event:*

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class ExistingClass
    {
        enum MyEnum
        {
            myInt
        }
    }
}

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class ModClass
    {
        public int myInt;
    }
}
```

In this example, because `ModClass` was modified, all its code would somehow be thrown to a parser which would get the fields (in this case only `myInt`) and then `ExistingClass` would have an enum with all the parsed fields names in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) Is there a way to intercept the Save event to

You can achieve it via [DocumentEventsClass.DocumentSaved Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.documenteventsclass.documentsaved)

> (2) get ModClass's code and then

You can get code via roslyn, for more information, please refer to:

https://www.filipekberg.se/2011/10/20/using-roslyn-to-parse-c-code-files/

> (3) parse it so I get the fields for example [I can do that part] and finally 
>    (4) automatically write related stuff directly in ExistingClass (or completely regenerate ExistingClass's code.

you can also generate new code via roslyn, the following sample for your reference.

[Using the open source released "roslyn" to read code file and generate new code files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879776/using-the-open-source-released-roslyn-to-read-code-file-and-generate-new-code)

Comment: Thanks for the examples Cole. I don't want to diverge too much from the original question but where should I be using DocumentSaved event ? Do I have to make a VS extension that will always run when my VS is open ? I know a bit about VSX for commands and such, but when it comes to "always-running extension" I'm pretty clueless. Any tips ?

Comment: it seems that you need to use DTE.Events to register to item added events and other events. For more information, please refer to:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f63cf959-16d9-44f8-8f9e-ea1f6063ce16/how-to-observe-changes-of-a-project-such-as-file-added-removed-file-content-changed-?forum=vsx

Comment: Yeah I've seen that already but if you take Mathias Herbaux's answer there for example, I don't understand Where that code should be. The use of the events seem pretty straight foward, but I don't see what `Constructor` refers to there. Is it in a VSX project on the side ? If so, how does it constantly run to monitor the events ? I hope my confusion makes sense to you; my original question is pretty broad on that part because like I said I haven't found any thorough explanation for such things.